# Fijar una cabecera de una tabla en php

Tags: php, html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo una tabla html y quiero fijar la cabecera pero al momento de hacerlo se me reduce el tamaño de los th y se descuadra toda la tabla

```
thead,tbody tr{
display:table;
width:100%;
table-layout:fixed;
```

}
thead {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}

Tiempo De Entrega a Domicilio (Facturas)</strong></font>-->



Factura
Fecha Factura
Cliente
H.Salida
H.Entrega
H.LLegada
Fecha Entrega
Hrs.Recibo Factura 
Chofer
Vehiculo
Direccion
Tiempo Final de entrega
Estatus

Answer (score 5):

El problema no lo tienes con php ni con HTML, sino con CSS (aunque ahí también está la solución...)

No he podido probarlo, pero sospecho que el causante es:

```css
thead
{
    position:fixed;
}
```

Bien, para corregir de una forma sencilla los efectos secundarios de darle `position: fixed` a la cabecera (el problema viene porque "se deprende" de la tabla y pierde el ancho forzado de las columnas del tbody) primero añadiría una clase a todas las columnas (th y td):

```html
<thead> 
    <tr class="titles">
        <th class="col1">Factura</th>
        <th class="col2">Fecha Factura</th>
        <th class="col3">Cliente</th>
        <th class="col4">H.Salida</th>
        ...
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    <tr class="data">
        <td class="col1">$factura</td>
        <td class="col2">$fecha_Factura</td>
        <td class="col3">$cliente</td>
        <td class="col4">$h_salida</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Y por último, ampliaría el CSS, usando esas clases para dar el tamaño deseado a cada columna (puedes usar pixeles, porcentajes o la unidad que prefieras...)

```css
thead
{
    position:fixed;
}

thead th,
tbody td {                // Aquí establecemos un ancho por defecto para todas,
    width: 60px;          // de ésta forma sólo forzamos el ancho de los
}                         // que lo necesiten

thead th.col2,
tbody td.col2 {
    width: 80px;
}

thead th.col3,
tbody td.col3 {
    width: 200px;
}

...
```

Comment: el class="col1 " para que me sirve

Comment: es necesario para localizar los elementos desde css, de otra forma cambiarías todas las tablas...

Comment: sigue igual aun con los valores fijos no hay otra forma de fijar la cabecera aunque no sea con css ??

Comment: CSS es la forma correcta de hacerlo... si actualizas tu código te podré decir dónde está el problema

Comment: ya resolvi el problema muchas gracias